# Maat: RuntimeError: LoaderLIEF::parse_binary(): Couldn't parse file './myFile.out'

Tags: symbolic-execution, maat

I'm running the [maat](https://maat.re/tutorials/get_started.html) symbolic executor on my MacOS with the following code.

Command I ran to get my binary code:

```bash
gcc myFile.c -o myFile.out
```

Maat python code:

```py
from maat import MaatEngine, ARCH, OS, BIN
m = MaatEngine(ARCH.X64, OS.LINUX)
m.load("./myFile.out", BIN.ELF64, args=[b"hello"], load_interp=False)
m.run()
```

However, running this is getting me the following error:

```
RuntimeError: LoaderLIEF::parse_binary(): Couldn't parse file './myFile.out'
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OS.LINUX` won't work on a macOS. You'll have to run your code on a linux machine.